# Creating a switch statement to convert Color class data types to String type

Tags: java, methods, colors, constructor, switch-statement

I am currently trying to create a switch statement that upon using getColor(), typing the color as a string sets the Primative Color type of Color.red (or other) to variable color. I apologize in advance if I am unable to even ask the question properly. I started programming 4 weeks ago.

```
public class ChooseAColor {
private Color color

//default color
public Color defaultColor(){
this.color = Color.red


public Color getColor(Color color){
    switch (color){
        case "Red":
            return color = java.awt.Color.red;
            break;
        case "Black":
            return java.awt.Color.black;
            break;
        case "Blue":
            return color = java.awt.Color.blue;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Then trying to call and print

```
public class TestChooseAColor{
ChooseAColor myColor = new ChooseAColor();

System.out.println("My favorite color is: " + myColor.getColor("Red")
```

I am expecting an output of

```
My favorite color is red
```

However, I am getting

```
java: incompatible types: java.awt.Color cannot be converted to int
```

Comment: You can't use a switch statement on a class (in this case, `Color`). That is why it is giving the error... It may be trying to convert `Color` into `int`. You can only use switch statements on int, char, String*, enums...

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. Looks like the problem is with your method. Why don't you change the parameter from `public Color getColor(Color color){` into `public Color getColor(String color){`?

After all, in your print message, you are giving your method a String, not a Color. So if you want to give it a String, then it would make sense that your method parameter should accept Strings.

Also, you might want to do something about those return statements. Why are you trying to set color while returning? Why not just return?

Instead of this:

```
return color = java.awt.Color.red;
```

Try this:

```
return java.awt.Color.red;
```

Lastly, it looks like you have some unnecessary `break;` statements. If you are returning a value, then there is no need for a break, right?

But don't forget that you DO need to return a value, so it looks like that default will need something INSTEAD of a break;

Maybe you can use that `defaultColor()` method from your code? (with a proper return statement, as mentioned earlier)